# How do I avoid double borders between lists?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using a list view in which I have an xml referencing drawable/list as follows:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 //For the borders
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    //For the background color of cells 
    <item android:top="1px"
          android:left="0dp"
          android:right="0dp"
          android:bottom="1px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#262626" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The above code is basically used to define the borders and the background color of cells. However, I want to be able to use line for the borders instead of rectangle so that the bottom border of one rectangle doesnt leave a 1 dp gap between the top border of another rectangle below it.
Please refer the image below:

[image]

As you can see from the image, the rectangular bottom border below BOK.L is a little off showing a gap between the top rectangular border of GOOG.OQ  Is there a way to fix this such that both the borders either overlap on top of each other and no such double line gap appears or is there a way I can define a line shape such that it is defined above and below all the cells in the pic without a gap?

Any clue?

Thanks!
Justin

The xml file referencing the same  (drawable/list) is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/list"
    android:padding="4dp"
     >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/symbol"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/search_autosuggest_header_text"
        foo:customFont="Roboto-Bold.ttf"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/last_container"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        foo:customFont="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/symbol"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/last_container"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/search_autosuggest_item_subtitle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/last_container"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/net_change_container" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_back"
            style="@style/TextView.ListsTextView"
            android:layout_width="87dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last"
            style="@style/TextView.ListsTextView"
            android:layout_width="87dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/net_change_container"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/percent_change_container" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/net_change_back"
            style="@style/TextView.ListsTextView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/net_change"
            style="@style/TextView.ListsTextView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/percent_change_container"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percent_change_back"
            style="@style/TextView.ListsTextView"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            foo:customFont="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percent_change"
            style="@style/TextView.ListsTextView"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also,@jboi  with with your fix the screen that I get is:
 [image]

Comment: Remove the `android:top` and the rest of the properties from the `layer-list`. In the adapter `getView()` then get the background of the row view, cast it to a `LayerDrawable` and then use the `setLayerInset()` method to show the proper dividers: top and bottom for the first element in the list(position == 0), only bottom for every other element. Remember to reset the insets if you have a convert view available.

Comment: is there an easier way around it ? as I dont have an adapter for it specifically and I have no clue how to cast it to the same, can you explain programmatically please? thanks!

Comment: nvm,I got it working, followed the same lines as you suggested.  can you copy paste this thingy as an answer so i can give you 25+ for the right answer and 50+ for the bounty and heads up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not have double selectors(and in proper positions like also at the top, at the bottom) you have two cases that you need to tackle, the top element(which needs the selector at the top and bottom) plus every other row which needs the selector only at the bottom(the top will be covered by the selector of the previous element). This has to be done in code, in your adapter(if you were using a simple table you could have just made one drawable for the top element and one for the other elements):

- remove the properties like `android:top`, `android:bottom` etc from the `layer-list`(as you'll be setting those in code)
- in the `getView()` method of the adapter retrieve the background of the row view(which will be a `LayerDrawable`)
- based on the position you have(mainly 0 vs any oher position) use the `LayerDrawable.setLayerInset()` method and set the inset for the layer with index 1(if that is your complete drawable): top **and** bottom for the first element, top(with a value of 0) and bottom for every other position

Comment: do you happen to have any clue about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256509/how-do-i-resolve-the-authentication-message-that-keeps-popping-up-in-a-webview

Comment: @JusticeBauer Sorry, but I don't know how to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could play with `ListView` params `android:divider` and `android:dividerHeight`, to set a line separator of the color and height you want.

Comment: I have used those in the cells where I can use it, but this one is a different case where I need to use the layer-list, is there a way to modify this instead to suit it to lines?

Comment: I see, sorry, never used `layer-lists`. What about setting android:top o android:bottom to 0px?

Comment: Mmh too bad, I'll give it a try myself and let you know if find out something else.

Comment: any clue about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256509/how-do-i-resolve-the-authentication-message-that-keeps-popping-up-in-a-webview/19256608?noredirect=1#comment28533391_19256608 ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for having two lines is, that the background (second layer) lets shine thru the white part on both ends, at the bottom and the top. Therefore every list entry gets a white line on top and on bottom. As list items have a small distance between each other you see two lines.

Two things you need to do

- For each item, let only one (top **or** bottom) shine thru. Therefore you get only one line per item. The drawable XML for an item:

  ```
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
  <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/white" />
      <corners android:radius="0dp" />
  </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:top="1dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <solid android:color="#262626" />
          <corners android:radius="0dp" />
      </shape>
  </item>
  </layer-list>
  ```
- For the whole list, you need the drawable that shows the one missing line. The drawable XML for this looks nearly the same. Just bottom and top is exchanged:

  ```
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
  <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/white" />
      <corners android:radius="0dp" />
  </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:top="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="1dp">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <solid android:color="#262626" />
          <corners android:radius="0dp" />
      </shape>
  </item>
  </layer-list>
  ```

Comment: that didn't resolve it, still have the issue with the top bottom border missing :(

Comment: I'm not if I understood you right. You want to show a list view with a line (and only a line) between each item. Additionally you want a line on top and on on bottom of the whole list. Is that right? Can you post the Xml of an item and the layout xml of the listview, please?

Comment: Please check the edited question for the xml and the corresponding screen that i get with your suggested fix

Comment: Looks better. We do not have the double lines any more, right? therefore we miss the last bottom line. I edit my answer to reflect what I suggest.

Comment: erm? how do i connect them both in the given xml??

Comment: doesnt that lead back to the same problem we started with?

Comment: That actually doesn't do anything and doesn't make sense either. You must really consider looking at your java code and setting the divider to null so it doesn't overlap and then remove the rectangle to include "line" shape

Comment: I don't know how?I tried everything including line shape, i am just not getting any results with line shapes

Comment: What really surprises me is that I get downgraded - even when a part of the answer was given. You can connect the second Xml by copying it in a drawable and use it with `android:background="@drawable/..."` just like you've done with each item in your Xml RelativeLayout.

Comment: I didn't downgrade you, probably the other guy did. Anyways, it leads to the same issue :\

Comment: will give u a heads up so it counteracts the downgrade effect

Comment: Thanks :-) I understand that the Xml you posted in your question (the RelativeLayout) is one item in the listview? In this case you can set the layout of the RelativeLayout and the background of the listview, right? The background of the RelativeLayout has its line at the top (first drawable). The listview has the line at the bottom (second drawable)

Comment: Actually I got to the root cause of the issue, will edit the question soon, it will be a simpler workaround with this change

Comment: the answer is above, however, do you have any clue about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256509/how-do-i-resolve-the-authentication-message-that-keeps-popping-up-in-a-webview/19256608?noredirect=1#comment28533391_19256608 ?